# Targeting different versions of Windows Phone OS

Tags: windows-phone-7

Now that Windows Phone Developer Tools 7.1 Beta is available for [download](https://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=77586864-ab15-40e1-bc38-713a95a56a05&displaylang=en), I was wondering if someone could tell me how easy / difficult it is to target OS version 7.0 once the new tools are installed. Is it like targeting different versions of the .NET framework, where you just need to change a project setting?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a new project, you'll be asked which platform you want to target. MSDN has been updated with new information about 7.1 SDK. In particular, here's the [targetting section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202937.aspx).

Comment: I've heard that it's possible to profile 7.0 apps on the emulator, but not on the device. 7.1 apps can be profiled on both.

Comment: I too heard this today from MS direct!